# how to align divs in a horizontal format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-float

I'm drawing 2 cirlces and having an img in between those 2 circles. I want to align all these in one horizontal line. All of these are inside a div of span4 width.

Here is my code.

```
<div id = "divid" span4>
```

**JS code**

```
var circle_style = "<div style = 'float:left'><canvas id='myCanvas' ></canvas></div><div style = 'float:left'><img src = 'img'></div><div style = 'float:left'><canvas id='myCanvas1'></canvas></div"


$("#divid").append(circle_style);

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 75;

context.beginPath();
context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.fillStyle = 'green';
context.fill();


var canvas2 = document.getElementById('myCanvas1');
var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
var centerX2= canvas2.width / 2;
var centerY2 = canvas2.height / 2;
var radius2 = 75;

context2.beginPath();
context2.arc(centerX2, centerY2, radius2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context2.fillStyle = 'green';
context2.fill();
```

Also, how do I insert text inside the circles?

Comment: what alignment you want ?  vertically aligned on the same line ?

Comment: Horizontal on the same line.

Comment: one against the other ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving inline style. That is a very bad practice.

You have not given `src` to image.

Try this:

JS:

```
var circle_style = "<div class='left vmiddle'><canvas id='myCanvas' ></canvas></div><div class='left vmiddle'><img src = 'img'></div><div class='left vmiddle'><canvas id='myCanvas1'></canvas></div>";
```

CSS:

```
img{height:50px;width:50px;background:#ccc;}
.vmiddle{vertical-align:middle;}
.left{display:inline-block;}
#divid{min-width:650px;}
```

[Demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/x2WF9/2)

[Output here.](http://jsfiddle.net/x2WF9/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: he wants them align horizontally i think

Comment: means not all in one line?

Comment: Point noted that inline styling is a bad practise. Thanks, but I wanted all of them to be horizontal, not vertical.

Comment: all div on separate line?

Comment: i checked your demo I saw 2 circles one on top of the other

Comment: No, all divs on one horizontal line.

Comment: @Hiral - My concern is whether this will work under span4 width or not? Let me check. Thanks

Comment: Not working. Its similar to what your demo shows. I want something like what your output shows.

Comment: Any idea? I guess span4 width is not letting me do so. Is it?

Comment: Yes, because `canvas` has width more than that of circle. I have updated answer. is it what you want?

Comment: Exactly.That what I want. Let me try it out. Thanks